# WordPress is adding absolute path to my image multiple times

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a quite specific problem to solve today - I just can't get my head wrapped around it. Makes totally no sense for me...

It's about a live site: http://rawrockchick.com/#testimonial-slider

If you scroll down to the testimonials on the home page (the link above should bring you there) you'll see that the **slider arrows are missing**. For a reason I can't figure out the URL is prepended a couple of times before the image src:

`<img src="http://rawrockchick.comhttp://rawrockchick.comhttp://rawrockchick.com/media/manual/slider-arrow-left.png">`

This wasn't the case two weeks ago, without anybody consciously touching it. I first thought of some Javascript thing happening with the bootstrap slider, but as you can see the testimonial image itself is not affected, even though it's placed in the exact way as the sliders are.

The whole slider is a very simple bootstrap carousel. Excerpts (relevant section) of the code:

```
<div class="item active">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8">

<p>"An up-and-coming UK raw food teacher and songstress, Barbara Fernandez has it going on! This girl can do food prep! Her Raw Mexican food is amazing"</p>
<p class="testimonial-author">Nomi Shannon</p>
<p class="testimonial-role">rawgourmet.com</p>

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#testimonial-slider" data-slide="prev"><img src="/media/manual/slider-arrow-left.png"></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#testimonial-slider" data-slide="next"><img src="/media/manual/slider-arrow-right.png"></a>

</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="/media/test-nomi-150.jpg" class="img-responsive hidden-xs hidden-sm img-circle" style="margin-left:25px;">
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

As you can see the images are inserted the exact same way.

## What I tried already (no change):

- I moved the `<img src="/media/manual/slider-arrow-left.png">` out of the link and placed it directly under the *working* image, the same strange behavior occurs for the slider arrow (by this test I wanted to make sure there's no jquery rule affecting only that one column of the slider, or the `a` tag).
- Hardcoding absolute image URL (`src="http://rawrockchick.com/media/manual/slider-arrow-left.png"`)
- WordPress PHP query for image URL (`src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/media/manual/slider-arrow-left.png"`)

I'd be very thankful if anyone had any ideas about that phenomena. Or idea how to debug it further.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Bootstrap javasript html or carousel -- add a wordpress tag on this question.  look in your configuration. You are using that path in posts via the php used but it's probably that you need to use the theme path or some other path to get it to work. It could be your .htaccess file, which unless you are familiar with that, don't fiddle with it.

Comment: I'm not sure where it comes from - why do you assume it's coming from PHP/Wordpress? Why is `<img src="/media/manual/slider-arrow-right.png">` treated entirely different than `<img src="/media/test-nomi-150.jpg" class="img-responsive hidden-xs hidden-sm img-circle" style="margin-left:25px;">` in PHP? 

Thanks for making the title clearer though!

Comment: I could be, but unlikely, php or wordpress but it's probably an .htaccess file inside that directory that is putting the double url.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Christina! But there is no .htaccess file in that directory - and note that the image that displays correctly is in that same directory. The .htaccess in the roots folder has only the WordPress defaults set. -> I'm still clueless.

Comment: One is /media/manual/ the other is just /media/ that's a different directory, even though the parent is the same. For now, why not move the arrows into the /media directory. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Christina You're right of course, and: Holy moly, that opens up a whole new era of strage behaviour. Total unpredictable things are happening. It now _sometimes_ works. Super weird. I think I'll follow the trail of Jrod (below) a bit more, for getting more predictable results (i.e. ditching the shortcode).

Comment: Update: Nope, it wasn't the shortcode either. It doesn't matter if it's inserted via a shortcode or not. Behaviour is the same. Happens also when inserted directly into code AND hardcoded URL. Brings me back to .htaccess or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Found it out via disabling plugin for plugin that a Pinterest hover button plugin ([this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pinterest-pin-it-button-for-images/) to be precise) was causing that mysterious phenomena.

Thanks for all the answers and hints!

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure why you are getting a double URL but using an absolute path to your image could help solve things.

```
<img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/media/test-nomi-150.jpg" class="img-responsive hidden-xs hidden-sm img-circle" style="margin-left:25px;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried this and I also tried the URL hardcoded: no change.

Comment: Looking at the source code the urls are being added on the server side.

Are you positive you are looking at the correct code snippet/file?
Is the slideshow being implemented by a plugin?
Are there hooks or filters being run on this snippet?
Is this a shortcode?

Comment: It's indeed inserted via a shortcode which is generated by the "Shortcodes Pro" plugin. Sorry for not mentioning it before - wanted to keep it lean and thought that didn't matter so much because it worked before. I see now that this might have to do with the actual  reason...

Comment: Update @Jrod: It doesn't matter if it's inserted via a shortcode or not. Behaviour is the same. Happens also when inserted directly into code AND hardcoded URL.

Comment: Check your General Settings and make sure the WordPress URL and site URL are correct. Those would likely cause other issues to but might as well check.

Again you are positive you are editing the correct file for this code? I know it has happened to me before that duplicate code is in more than one file and no matter how many times I changed the code I didn't see the affect on the front end because I was changing the wrong file.

I've never used the shortcodes Pro plugin does it have any custom options where you might set a url or path to images etc?

Comment: thanks for the ongoing hints and advice. I meanwhile isolated the problem further and found out a plugin is causing it.